Definite integral $\int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}}{\sqrt{\cosh{x}-\cosh{b}}}dx$?
For positive $a$ and $b$, consider the integral
$$ I(a,b)=\int_b^\infty \frac{e^{-ax}}{\sqrt{\cosh{x}-\cosh{b}}}dx. $$
Does $I(a,b)$ have a closed-form expression (far-fetched hope)? If not, does it have a representation in terms of known special functions? As a last resort, can it at least be written in a power series in $b$ about zero?

Equivalently the integral can be rewritten as $$I(a,b) = \sqrt{2}e^{-ab}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2ax}}{\sqrt{\sinh\left(x+b\right)\sinh\left(x\right)}}dx$$ As may be more obvious in this representation, a series around $b=0$ has a nonintegrable singularity

Please edit your post to include any thoughts/attempts you’ve made so far.

@Grey I(a,b) is my attempt. The integral I’m actually interested in is a more complicated double integral that I’ve reduced to I(a,b). I did not want to clutter the question with irrelevant details.

@ClaudeLeibovici I used the angle sum/difference identities to get a product. There should not be a minus sign between the terms anymore.

@NinadMunshi. Sorry for that ! Stupid typo on my side. Cheers :-(

As @NinadMunshi wrote, using $x=2t+b$, you end with
$$I(a,b)=\sqrt{2}\, e^{-a b}\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-2 a t}}{\sqrt{\sinh (t) \sinh
   (t+b)}} \,dt$$
Using Mathematica, assuming $a>0$ and $b>0$ and a lot of simplifications
$$\color{blue}{I(a,b)=\frac {\sqrt {2 \pi ^3 }\,\sec (a\pi)\,e^{-\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right) b} }{ \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}-a\right)\, \Gamma (a+1)} \,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},a+\frac{1}{2};a+1;e^{-2 b}\right)}$$
If you prefer series expansions for small $b$, asumming $t>0$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sinh (t) \sinh(b+t)}}=\text{csch}(t)-\frac{\coth (t)\, \text{csch}(t)}{2}\, b +\frac{(\cosh (2 t)+5)\,
   \text{csch}^3(t)}{16}\, b^2 +O\left(b^3\right)$$ but this would make serious problems because of the nonintegrable singularity (just as @NinadMunshi commented).
$$\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},a+\frac{1}{2};a+1;c\right)=\frac{\Gamma (a+1)}{\sqrt{\pi } \,\Gamma\left(a+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \,
   \Gamma \left(n+a+\frac{1}{2}\right) } {\Gamma (n+1) \Gamma (n+a+1) } \,c^n$$
If $A_n$ is the summand, with $c=e^{-2b}$, asymptotically
$$\frac {A_{n+1}}{A_n}=e^{-2b} \left( 1-\frac{1}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}
   \right) \right)$$

This is not an answer really, only a solution from
$\tt Mathematica$:
\begin{align}
& \int_b^{\infty } \frac{\exp (-a x)}{\sqrt{\cosh (x)-\cosh (b)}} \, dx
\\[3mm] = & \
\sqrt{2}\,\exp(-ab) \left(\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sinh (x+b) \sinh(x)}}\right](2 a)\right)
\\[3mm] = &\
\frac{e^{-a b}\,\sqrt{2\pi}\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{1}{2}+a\right) \, _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+a;1+a;e^{-2b}\right)}{\sqrt{e^b}\,\Gamma (1+a)}
\end{align}
